# String + Jpa + Hibernate, force collection eager initialization on only specific method without transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

Very simple question and i would like a simple answer.
I'm loading one entity with many lazy collection associated.
This load is done outside a @Transactional method for personal reasons

right after loading the entity i try loading the collections but i get exception

```
final A cachedEntity = aRepository.find(entity.getDocument());
         final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
         session.beginTransaction();
         Hibernate.initialize(cachedEntity.getAddresses()); // exception right here
         cachedEntity.getAddresses().addAll(entity.getAddresses());
         cachedEntity.getPhones().addAll(entity.getPhones());
         cachedEntity.getEmails().addAll(entity.getEmails());
         session.close();


failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:  addresses, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

This is supposed to be super simple, what am i doing wrong?
please dont suggest annotate collections with eager or add @transactional to method

Comment: How do you expect JPA/Hibernate to read data lazily from the DB outside the session it was loaded in? The `find()` method is where it was loaded, then you open a new session and try to reference that lazy data there, but that original session is likely gone, so there entity is now detached and has no way to lazily load the missing data.

Comment: By the way, "I would like a simple answer" isn't realistic for any JPA questions other than the most trivial. ORM is complex stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple, I'll share to help others.
I knew there should be a way to tell jpa to force eager load a collection for one specific query only, and there is.

In the repository interface annotate the specific query you want to have eager load with

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"lazyCollectionA", "lazyCollectionB"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
   A find(/*PARAMETERS_HERE*/);
```

this way when spring builds this query it will create a inner join for the specified collections and eager initialize them.

Another approach would be specify the whole query in the `@Query` annotation specifing the inner joins you want. but as i want take advantage of spring auto generated queries i just use the @EntityGraph

Comment: this should be in baeldung and all tutorials....

Comment: Yes, Entity Graphs are the right solution for query-specific eager fetching. The question doesn't make it clear that eager fetching is an option, so you might want to consider stating that. It just says, "with many lazy loaded associations." Many people have an inherent fear of eager fetching and want to avoid it at all costs (which I think personally is a narrow view of things, we should be more flexible as you've shown here).